# Transform items from iterable with a sequence of unary functions

Tags: python, dictionary, transform, predicate, unary-function

I frequently find myself needing to apply a sequence of unary functions to a sequence of of the same length. My first thought is to go with `map()`, however this only takes a single function to be applied to all items in the sequence.

In the following code for example, I wish to apply `str.upper()` to the first item, and `int` to the second item in each `a`. "`transform`" is a place holder for the effect I'm after.

```
COLS = tuple([transform((str.upper, int), a.split(",")) for a in "pid,5 user,8 program,28 dev,10 sent,9 received,15".split()])
```

Is there some standard library, or other nice implementation that can perform a transformation such as this neatly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question, but I would splurge and buy an extra line of code for this. Split the records and their fields on line 1, finish tidying up on line 2. In other words, the thing you've chosen to factor out is not what I would have chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about...:

```
def transform(functions, arguments):
  return [f(a) for f, a in zip(functions, arguments)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s="pid,5 user,8 program,28 dev,10 sent,9 received,15".split()
>>> [ ( m.upper(),int(n)) for m, n in [i.split(",") for i in s ] ]
[('PID', 5), ('USER', 8), ('PROGRAM', 28), ('DEV', 10), ('SENT', 9), ('RECEIVED', 15)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using this:

```
def transform(unaries, iterable):
    return map(lambda a, b: a(b), unaries, iterable)
```

Comment: How does this perform with relation to Alex Martelli's answer, which looks somewhat simpler?